# How to request captcha solving by user using Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, captcha

I am coding a application which needs to take a CAPTCHA image, show it to the user and wait for him type it before proceed and submit the form.

I am already able to take the CAPTCHA image but I do not have any idea how to show it to the user and then stop my script until he types it on.

Does anyone could help me?

Cheers.

Comment: Use Google's reCaptcha. It is free and secure. Here is the link to the developer's guide: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

Comment: Captcha is part of the website loaded by Selenium. I wanna show it in my page, not a new one...

Answer (score 0):

This is really tricky question, but if I had to do it, I would use for

> a CAPTCHA image, show it to the user

the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). It allows you to manipulate the DOM and perform anything you need. In this case you can [append a container element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) for the image you already obtained.

As for

> any idea how to show it to the user and then stop my script until he types it on

I would suggest putting a simple condition, like if the text input contains any alpha-numeric value (easy to check with regex), or whatever value your CAPTCHA validation expects. Until condition is met - you can use `Thread.Sleep` for certain amount of time e.g. with 2 sec step between iterations. Also you can put time limit, avoiding infinite loops.

Hope this brings some light to your problem.